# Best program to restore NTFS partition table

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I have a drive that seems to have a lost partition table.  EaseUS and Photorec seemed to not know about any partitions, but restored about 1 TB of files from the disk, however they are all useless and corrupt (it probably guessed wrong about where they start and stop/fragmentation).  I think the only hope is recovering the partition table.  HDtune shows every sector as bad/red.  The drive does not mount in Windows or Linux, it can only be accessed as a physical device I guess.  Any hope? 2 TB NTFS WD20EARS SATA drive.  Disk Manager shows it as unallocated.

Comment: So, what actually happened to the drive?

Comment: It just started asking if you want to format the drive according to the owner.  It was in an external enclosure and I believe the power cord was yanked out, but my info is second hand.  I am helping out a college buddy, but data recovery is not my forte.

Comment: I am pretty sure the entire drive was one partition.

Comment: It was not a bootable drive, it was a data drive.

Comment: «Photorec seemed to not know about any partitions» Of course not, Photorec is a file carver. :)

Answer (score 0):

For restoring the partition table check the programs mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/676183/149510):
Partition Guru, Partition Wizard, etc